# In react login page,Only first time We have to manually type the home page address after entering email and pwd in react login page using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I created a react user authentication page using email and password. using firebase data base. but when i start my react web application by npm start. i redirect to http://localhost:3000/login.and when i enter the email and password it suppose to automatically redirect to home page http://localhost:3000/home but nothing happened. but i have to enter the homepage addresss manually http://localhost:3000/home to redirect to home page. and after that when i logout and try to login again, now this time it automatically redirect to homepage http://localhost:3000/home. after opening the project by npm start only first time i have to enter the homepage address manually to redirect the homepage.and after that it work normally as expected.

**here is my App.js code**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Signupform from './Components/pages/Signupform';
import Home from './Components/pages/Home';
import Protected from './Components/Protected';
import Login from './Components/pages/Login';

const isAuthenticated = () => {
  // Check if the user is authenticated based on your authentication mechanism
  // For example, check if the user's token is present in local storage
  return localStorage.getItem('token') !== null;
};

function App() {
  return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} exact />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signupform />} />
        {/* Protected route - Redirect to login if not authenticated */}
        <Route
          path="/protected"
          element={
            isAuthenticated() ? (
              <Protected />
            ) : (
              <Navigate to="/login" replace />
            )
          }
        />
        {/* Home route - Redirect to login if not authenticated */}
        {isAuthenticated?<Route path="/home"/>:<Route path='/login'/>}
        {/* <Route
          path="/home"
          element={isAuthenticated() ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />}
        /> */}
        {/* Redirect to login if not authenticated */}
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={
            isAuthenticated() ? (
              <Navigate to="/home" replace />
            ) : (
              <Navigate to="/login" replace />
            )
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
      </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

**and here is my Login.jsx file**

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import './Login.css';
import { FaUserAlt,FaLock } from "react-icons/fa";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';



const Login = () => {
    
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
   
    
     const navigate = useNavigate();
       
      


     const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        try {
            console.log("login testing");
            const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
            // console.log(userCredential);
            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log("user");
            localStorage.setItem('token', user.accessToken);
            console.log('Token stored:', user.accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log("redirecting to home");
            navigate("/");
            console.log("checking home file is called or not");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
    
    
  
    return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='wrapper'>

            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div className="input-box">
                <input type="email" placeholder='Your Email'   required
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) =>setEmail(e.target.value) }
                />
                <FaUserAlt className='icon'/>
            </div>
            <div className="input-box">
                <input type="password" placeholder='password'  
                 required
                 value={password}
                 onChange={(e) =>setPassword(e.target.value) }
                 />
                <FaLock className='icon' />
            </div>


            <button type='submit'>Login</button>

            <div className="Login-button">
            <p> Create an account? <Link to ="/signup">Create account</Link> </p>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
  )
}
export default Login;
```

**and here is my Home.jsx file**

```
import React from 'react';
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from './firebase';

const Home = () => {
  
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
console.log('User:', user);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    console.log('Logging out...');
    try {
        await signOut(auth);
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        navigate("/login");
        console.log('Navigated to login page');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error signing out:", error);
    }
};

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to React Firebase Auth using Email and password.</h1>
      <h2>{user && user.email}</h2>
      <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**Please solve this problem, getting very weird problem, i am providing you the hosted link so that you can also see the problem, here is the link**
[working website](https://react-firebase-auth-emai-899b6.web.app/login)
after login for moving into homepage put /home at the end.

I thought it was a routing issue. But its not i tried everything to solve this problem but nothing happened. Only first time after opening the page i am facing the issue to redirecting to homepage after authentication. and after i manually redirect the homepage and logout and try to login again this time it automatically redirect to homepage as expected.